# Splash Page with Pure CSS and close button

Tags: jquery, html, css, splash-screen

I found this Splash page with pure CSS code and try to figure out,

1. how I can make it stay instead of fading out and disappearing. I tried dozens of changes but could not find out, what to change just to make it stay where it is and only disappear, when the close button is clicked.
2. And additionaly I would like the close button (could be just a textlink, too) inside of the message div.
3. Last question: How can I switch of the rotating in to fading in and the fading out, to rotating out?

Here is the link to the code with example:
https://codepen.io/paulobrien/pen/AByuk

This is the HTML:

```
<h1>This is the page</h1>
<p><a href="#">Page content goes here : Page content goes here : </p>
<div class="overlay-wrap">
        <input type="checkbox" name="hide" id="hide">
        <label class="hide" for="hide">Close Now</label>
        <div class="overlay2">
                <div class="overlay">
                        <div class="overlay-inner">
                                <div class="message">
                                        <h2>This message will self destruct after 5 seconds</h2>
                                        <p>No javascript required - Lorem...</p>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

And here`s the CSS:

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
}
.overlay {
    opacity:0;
    position:fixed;
    top:-999em;
    left:-999em;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:table;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    -webkit-animation: splash 10s forwards;
  -moz-animation: splash 10s forwards; 
  -ms-animation: splash 10s forwards; 
  animation: splash 10s forwards;
}
.overlay-inner {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
.message {
    border:10px solid red;
    border-radius:10px;
    background:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:50%;
    text-align:left;
    padding:10px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes splash {
  0%  {opacity: 0;top:0;left:0;-webkit-transform:rotate(0) scale(0.2)}
    20% {opacity:1;-webkit-transform:rotate(720deg) scale(1.0)}
    60% {opacity:1;}
    99% {top:0;left:0;}
    100%{opacity:0;top:-999em;left:-999em;-webkit-transform:rotate(720deg) scale(1.0)}
}
@-moz-keyframes splash {
   0% {opacity: 0;top:0;left:0;-moz-transform:rotate(0) scale(0.2)}
    20% {opacity:1;-moz-transform:rotate(720deg) scale(1.0)}
    60% {opacity:1;}
    99% {top:0;left:0}
    100%{opacity:0;top:-999em;left:-999em;-moz-transform:rotate(720deg) scale(1.0)}
}
@-ms-keyframes splash {
   0% {opacity: 0;top:0;left:0;-ms-transform:rotate(0) scale(0.2)}
    20% {opacity:1;-ms-transform:rotate(720deg) scale(1.0)}
    60% {opacity:1;}
    99% {top:0;left:0}
    100%{opacity:0;top:-999em;left:-999em;-ms-transform:rotate(720deg) scale(1.0)}
}  
@keyframes splash {
  0%  {opacity: 0;top:0;left:0;transform:rotate(0) scale(0.2)}
    20% {opacity:1;transform:rotate(720deg) scale(1.0)}
    60% {opacity:1;}
    99% {top:0;left:0}
    100%{opacity:0;top:-999em;left:-999em;transform:rotate(720deg) scale(1.0)}
}
.overlay-wrap {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:99;
}
.overlay-wrap .hide {
    position:absolute;
    top:-999em;
    right:10px;
    opacity:0;
    color:#fff;
    border:5px solid #fff;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:200%;
    z-index:2;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-animation:10s fadein 2s forwards;
    -moz-animation:10s fadein 2s forwards;
    -ms-animation:10s fadein 2s forwards;
    animation:10s fadein 2s forwards;   
}
#hide {
    position:absolute;
    left:-999em;
    top:-999em;
}
.overlay2{
    position:absolute;
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition:all 2s;
    -moz-transition:all 2s;
    -ms-transition:all 2s;
    transition:all 2s ;
}
#hide:checked ~ div,#hide:checked ~ div *, #hide:checked + label {
 opacity:0;
 left:-999em;
 right:auto;
 top:-999em;
 pointer-events:none;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
 0% {opacity: 0;top:10px;}
 20% {opacity:1;top:10px;}
  80%{opacity:1;top:10px}
  100%{opacity:0;top:-999em}
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
 0% {opacity: 0;top:10px;}
 20% {opacity:1;top:10px;}
  80%{opacity:1;top:10px}
 100%{opacity:0;top:-999em
}
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
 0% {opacity: 0;top:10px;}
 20% {opacity:1;top:10px;}
 80%{opacity:1;top:10px}
 100%{opacity:0;top:-999em
}
@keyframes fadein {
 0% {opacity: 0;top:10px;}
 20% {opacity:1;top:10px;}
 80%{opacity:1;top:10px}
 100%{opacity:0;top:-999em}
}
```

Thank you in advance,
Atilla

**Update: Here`s the new Pen with the actual changes, that I have asked for**:
https://codepen.io/great2gether/pen/JJyjxY/

Answer (score 0):

He is using CSS3 keyframes. Look at the 4th line. First opacity is 0, then 1 and when 80% of the time is gone, the opacity will fall again to 0 the last 20% of time the keyframe is based on.

Delete the 4th line (sometimes only opacity regarding to the effect) in every keyframe and see what happens :)

```
@keyframes fadein {
 0% {opacity: 0;top:10px;}
 20% {opacity:1;top:10px;}
 80%{opacity:1;top:10px}
 100%{opacity:0;top:-999em}
}
```

Comment: Could not see much of a happening so far :/ Did it work for you when you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Change the last line of each `keyframes` from this:

```
100%{opacity:0;top:-999em;left:-999em;transform:rotate(720deg) scale(1.0)}
```

to this:

```
100%{opacity:1;top:0;left:0;transform:rotate(720deg) scale(1.0)}
```

The splash screen already has a close button, so no need to worry about that. But to prevent it from disappearing, change the last line of each `keyframes` from this:

```
100%{opacity:0;top:-999em}
```

to this:

```
100%{opacity:1;top:10px;}
```

Here is the modified code:

```css
html,body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
}
.overlay {
    opacity:0;
    position:fixed;
    top:-999em;
    left:-999em;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:table;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    -webkit-animation: splash 10s forwards;
  -moz-animation: splash 10s forwards; 
  -ms-animation: splash 10s forwards; 
  animation: splash 10s forwards;
}
.overlay-inner {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
.message {
    border:10px solid red;
    border-radius:10px;
    background:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:50%;
    text-align:left;
    padding:10px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes splash {
  0%  {opacity: 0;top:0;left:0;-webkit-transform:rotate(0) scale(0.2)}
    20% {opacity:1;-webkit-transform:rotate(720deg) scale(1.0)}
    60% {opacity:1;}
    99% {top:0;left:0;}
    100%{opacity:1;top:0;left:0;-webkit-transform:rotate(720deg) scale(1.0)}
}
@-moz-keyframes splash {
   0% {opacity: 0;top:0;left:0;-moz-transform:rotate(0) scale(0.2)}
    20% {opacity:1;-moz-transform:rotate(720deg) scale(1.0)}
    60% {opacity:1;}
    99% {top:0;left:0}
    100%{opacity:1;top:0;left:0;-moz-transform:rotate(720deg) scale(1.0)}
}
@-ms-keyframes splash {
   0% {opacity: 0;top:0;left:0;-ms-transform:rotate(0) scale(0.2)}
    20% {opacity:1;-ms-transform:rotate(720deg) scale(1.0)}
    60% {opacity:1;}
    99% {top:0;left:0}
    100%{opacity:1;top:0;left:0;-ms-transform:rotate(720deg) scale(1.0)}
}  
@keyframes splash {
  0%  {opacity: 0;top:0;left:0;transform:rotate(0) scale(0.2)}
    20% {opacity:1;transform:rotate(720deg) scale(1.0)}
    60% {opacity:1;}
    99% {top:0;left:0}
    100%{opacity:1;top:0;left:0;transform:rotate(720deg) scale(1.0)}
}
.overlay-wrap {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:99;
}
.overlay-wrap .hide {
    position:absolute;
    top:-999em;
    right:10px;
    opacity:0;
    color:#fff;
    border:5px solid #fff;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:200%;
    z-index:2;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-animation:10s fadein 2s forwards;
    -moz-animation:10s fadein 2s forwards;
    -ms-animation:10s fadein 2s forwards;
    animation:10s fadein 2s forwards;   
}
#hide {
    position:absolute;
    left:-999em;
    top:-999em;
}
.overlay2{
    position:absolute;
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition:all 2s;
    -moz-transition:all 2s;
    -ms-transition:all 2s;
    transition:all 2s ;
}
#hide:checked ~ div,#hide:checked ~ div *, #hide:checked + label {
 opacity:0;
 left:-999em;
 right:auto;
 top:-999em;
 pointer-events:none;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
 0% {opacity: 0;top:10px;}
 20% {opacity:1;top:10px;}
  80%{opacity:1;top:10px;}
  100%{opacity:1;top:10px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
 0% {opacity: 0;top:10px;}
 20% {opacity:1;top:10px;}
  80%{opacity:1;top:10px;}
 100%{opacity:1;top:10px;}
}
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
 0% {opacity: 0;top:10px;}
 20% {opacity:1;top:10px;}
 80%{opacity:1;top:10px;}
 100%{opacity:1;top:10px;}
}
@keyframes fadein {
 0% {opacity: 0;top:10px;}
 20% {opacity:1;top:10px;}
 80%{opacity:1;top:10px;}
 100%{opacity:1;top:10px;}
}
```

```html
<h1>This is the page</h1>
<p><a href="#">Page content goes here : Page content goes here : </p>
<div class="overlay-wrap">
        <input type="checkbox" name="hide" id="hide">
        <label class="hide" for="hide">Close Now</label>
        <div class="overlay2">
                <div class="overlay">
                        <div class="overlay-inner">
                                <div class="message">
                                        <h2>This message will self destruct after 5 seconds</h2>
                                        <p>No javascript required - Lorem...</p>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have replaced the lines you mention at he following places:               `@-webkit-keyframes splash 
@-moz-keyframes splash 
@-ms-keyframes splash 
@keyframes splash 
`  but nothing changed so far.

Comment: I know, it was a copy/paste mistake and I was updating my answer when you commented. Check it out now.

Comment: Ah ok perfect - very cool! Yes now it stays in its place and only disappears when you click the button. Thanks so much!

Comment: Could you also help me out, with how I could make it fade-in instead of rotate-in? For some websites i think this version might be a little to playful. Fading in fits like every website, I`d say. Would be awesome :) I prepared a new pen with your updated code right here and changed the Close into an X - https://codepen.io/great2gether/pen/JJyjxY

Comment: That's easy. Just delete `rotate(720deg)` in each `keyframes`.

Comment: Thank you very, very much. Works just like you said!